# insertion sort in c , need correction

Tags: c, insertion-sort

I am trying to create an insertion sort in C. We used the following code in school, but it's not working.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
        int a[6] = {5,8,3,2,9,1};
        int i,j, key;
        int countArraySize = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);


        for (i = 0; i < countArraySize; ++i)
        {
            key = a[i];
            j = i - 1;

            while( j>=0 && key < a[j]) {
                a[j+1] = a[j];
                j--;
            }

            a[j+1] = key;
            printf("%d\n", a[j+1]);
        }


        return 0;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: "it's not working" is almost never an adequate problem description. If you want help then please take the time to explain your problem more clearly. Specifically, provide the input, the expected result/output and the actual result/output (the latter two are missing). And have you tried in any way to debug this (apart from posting on SO)? For example, using a debugger?

Comment: I'll give you a hint: Your `printf` is printing every `key` at the point it is encountered in the input array. That is, you are just printing out the unsorted array values. How could you change the code to print out the sorted values instead?

Comment: Tip: Print out the values of `j` and think about negative indices.

Comment: stackofverflow is not the place for solving homework assignments. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @kaylum , i tried everything to sort this but it never worked, i spends hours and hours debugging this according to my knowledge. so i ended up posting this on Stackoverflow . infact i wanted them to appear in ascending order. but there is wrong with my code which i don't seem to understand. i understand your mentioned J , i tried with i , key , plus , minus and everything according to my knowledge.

Comment: @LearningPHPOOP Seems you did not understand my hint. Have a look at the answer below to see if that makes sense now.

Comment: @kaylum is right. Your sort is fine.  Your printf is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sort is correct but you are simply printing out the wrong thing. You should not be printing out during the sort. As it is, the code just prints out each key as it is encountered in the input. Instead, the printing should be done *after* the sort has completed. That is, remove the `printf` from within the current `for` loop and put it into a seperate `for` loop after the sorting has completed:

```
for (i = 0; i < countArraySize; ++i) {
    key = a[i];
    j = i - 1;

    while( j>=0 && key < a[j]) {
        a[j+1] = a[j];
        j--;
    }

    a[j+1] = key;

    /* FOLLOWING LINE REMOVED */
    /* printf("%d\n", a[j+1]); */
}

/* ADDED THIS BLOCK TO PRINT THE SORTED ARRAY */
for (i = 0; i < countArraySize; ++i) {
     printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: seems like when i was printing out this in a loop at stage it was unsorted, so the sorting is done only when the loop is over, then we can print this out. thanks for your help. it worked